# LMFIT on Python: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scientific-computing, lmfit

I am trying to create an curve fitting program using LMFIT on python (Anaconda) but I keep receiving the same error message: **TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars**. I was able to perform an optimization using just one function, but when I try to optimize a function that calls other user-defined functions, I get this error.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
import scipy.special as sp
from scipy import integrate
import lmfit as lm


#Defining the first function.
def function1(alpha,q,s,l):

    Intensity = alpha**2 + q -s*alpha / (5*l)
    return Intensity

#Defining a second function that will perform a integration over the first function.
def integrate_function(q,s,l):
    func_parameters = {
        'q':q,
        's':s,
        'l':l,
    }
    to_be_integrated = lambda alpha: function1(alpha, **func_parameters)
    result, error = integrate.quad(to_be_integrated, 0, 10)
    return result

#Setting up the LMFIT model. Here I also provide the initial guess for the parameters.
integrate_function_model = lm.Model(integrate_function, independent_vars=['q'])
integrate_function_model.set_param_hint('s', value=2, min=-10.0, max=20.0, vary=True)
integrate_function_model.set_param_hint('l', value=3, min=1.0, max=10.0, vary=True)
initial_params = integrate_function_model.make_params()

#Creating data to be fitted (I also add some noise)
#Here I set s=1.5 and l=5.0 and I want the optimization routine to be able to find out these numbers.
x_data = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y_data = np.zeros(len(x_data))
for i in range(len(x_data)):
    y_data[i] = integrate_function(x_data[i],1.5,5.0)  + 5.0*np.random.random()


#Fitting the data.
fitting = integrate_function_model.fit(y_data, initial_params, q=x_data, method='leastsq')

#Printing original data and fitted model.
pyplot.plot(x_data, y_data, color='green', lw=2)
pyplot.plot(x_data, fitting.best_fit, color='blue', lw=2)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: line of the error?

Comment: File "C:\Users\var\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 448, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

Comment: No, the line error in YOUR code (the top of the stack trace). It's impossible to tell from that

Comment: What I don't understand is this cumbersome fiddling with `lambda`, why not use the [`args()` option of `quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html)

Comment: mikuszefski, you're right. I will try to make it look cleaner with the args keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs when your function `integrate_function` is called with a `np.array` as an argument for `q`:

```
>>> integrate_function(1,1,1)
333.33333333333337
>>> integrate_function(np.array([1,2]),1,1)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

This happens during `output.fit` where `integrate.quad` is called. `quad` is not able to handle vectorized input, which is happening in your case.

One option to fix this would be to change `integrate_function` to handle the case where `q` is an array accordingly, for example by manually including a loop over all values in `q`:

```
def integrate_function(q,s,l):
    # Make q iterable if it is only a float/int
    if not hasattr(q, '__iter__'):
        q = np.array([q])

    result = []
    for q0 in q: 
        func_parameters = {
        'q':q0,
        's':s,
        'l':l,
    }
        to_be_integrated = lambda alpha: function1(alpha, **func_parameters)
        result.append(integrate.quad(to_be_integrated, 0, 10)[0])
    return np.array(result)
```

Executing your code with the modified `integrate_function` then yields the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much jdamp. That strategy has made it work. I did not realize the problem was on the q variable at all!